# Flask root path for sub package structure

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm looking for advice in setting up a python repo with multiple packages, including a flask project. This may be as much a docker issues as a python/flask one, so I'm open to any patterns that will help out here.

My app structure is something like this (note: this looks like namespace packaging but I have `setup.py` configured so each package is its own namespace):

```
my_app
|--setup.py
|--src/
    |--my_flask_app/
        |--__init__.py
        |--static/
        |--templates/
    |--some_other_module/
        |--__init__.py
```

I'm having issues with this pattern though from the development side. Basically I know that I can override `root_path` with `Flask(__name__, root_path='/app/src/my_flask_app)'` to let it find the appropriate source directory. However, this needs to be changed depending on whether I'm running it in Docker image or locally.

For example, if I print the `app.root_path` running locally (without modifying it) I see `/Users/username/Documents/my_app/src/my_flask_app`. If I run this in docker, it must be `/app/src/my_flask_app` to work properly (defaults to `/app/my_flask_app` without modification, which is broken).

My primary question: Is there some easy way to handle this, structure the project/dockerfile to make this so I don't have to keep changing this between local and docker run instances? Should I be using `Flask(instance_path=)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, this seems to work for both docker and local:

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, root_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd() + '/src/my_flask_app'))
```